# NumPy Incorrect shape of elements for internal rectangular array of non-rectangular array

Tags: python, numpy

In the following code below, I construct an array composed of two different arrays. This code example simulates the original problem's data, which is why there are two different arrays and they are accessed in this way. Once the array has been constructed, converted to numpy and transposed I want to access just the second list. However, once I have this second list, it is composed of list objects despite being rectangular (The values are in the format of (10,5)) Does anyone know why this happens? Is there some way to avoid it while still accessing the data in this way?

```
big_array = []

big_array.append([[0, 0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
big_array.append([[0, 0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
big_array.append([[0, 0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
big_array.append([[0, 0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
big_array.append([[0, 0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
big_array.append([[0, 0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
big_array.append([[0, 0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
big_array.append([[0, 0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
big_array.append([[0, 0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
big_array.append([[0, 0],[0,0,0,0,0]])

big_array = np.asarray(big_array).transpose()
eval_array = big_array[1]
print(eval_array)
print(eval_array.shape)
```

Here is the output of the prints:

```
[list([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) list([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) list([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
 list([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) list([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) list([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
 list([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) list([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) list([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
 list([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])]
(10,)
```

Clearly, the array in the above output is rectangular, but I suppose it has not been recognized as such.

Comment: Because your array is not rectangular. It will probably result in an array of object dtype that contains lists as elements instead of integers.

Comment: I suppose the point of confusion here is that when accessing the array using big_array[1], the result is actually rectangular. But you are correct that it is interpreted as object dtype, which is the problem - thanks.

Comment: `big_array` is a (2,10) object dtype array containing lists.  `big_array[1]` gives you one row, but it still contains lists.  `np.stack(big_array[1])` will join those lists into a (10,5) array.

Comment: It seems odd that the transpose would still function correctly given that they are lists, but I suppose it is designed to handle list-like structures too - which mine is. Thanks, you've cleared up a lot for me here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When initializing an array that is not a rectangle, the elements are objects. When transposing this representation, even if the internal elements are then rectangular, NumPy will retain the object type for these arrays. The reason you're seeing what you're seeing is because you transposed an array of objects, and got an array of objects as a result.

It is possible to get the correct shape with the following code:

```
np.asarray(eval_array.tolist())
```

The way to avoid this would be to start with a rectangular array.

Answer (score 0):

You are stating that "Clearly, the array is rectangular", but that is not true :)

Have a look at this `[[0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]`. This is a one-dimensional array that contains:

- an array with 2 elements
- an array with 5 elements

This is not rectangular.

`[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]` (5,2) or `[[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]` (2,5) are.

In order to achieve the array of arrays effect that you seem to be looking for, you need the sizes of the inner arrays (that are part of the same dimension) to be equal.

```
big_array = []

big_array.append([[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
big_array.append([[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
big_array.append([[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
big_array.append([[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
big_array.append([[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
big_array.append([[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
big_array.append([[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
big_array.append([[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
big_array.append([[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]])
big_array.append([[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]])

np_arr = np.array(big_array)
np_arr.shape
> (10, 2, 5)
```

Comment: Thanks, I do understand this - but my intention was to point out that the array I've taken from the non-rectangular array is rectangular, rather than the initial non-rectangular array being rectangular. This is shown in the output below the code. However, I do see that if my array was initially rectangular it would indeed have worked just fine. Which is an interesting addition. It seems like when starting with a non rectangular array, the internal elements will never be understood as something other than objects. I will edit the main question to make this more clear.

Comment: But you are using the original (non-properly shaped python array) when creating the NumPy array. What else were you expecting to happen?

Comment: I suppose I was expecting numpy to recognize that it was a rectangular array after it was transposed, or after I took the row. Typically I've found that numpy is able to do that, but I suppose in the case of an array of objects the type just remains objects - which is some new knowledge for me.